# Field with Lookup value fails to save in Start a Task Process action

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Here is the scenario:

1. I added a **Start a Task Process** action.
2. I clicked **Process Settings**. Start a Task Process dialog is shown.
3. I entered the **Participants** and **Task Title**.
4. I clicked "Open editor for body" button for the Description.
5. I clicked "Add or Change Lookup" button.
6. Data Source is **Current Item**.
7. Field from source is *Field Name*.
8. Return field as: **Lookup Value (as Text)**.
9. I clicked OK in String Builder dialog.
10. I clicked OK in Start a Task Process dialog.
11. I clicked **Process Settings** again.
12. Surprisingly, all the details I entered are ***gone***.

Troubleshooting I did:

1. I tried changing the field with a different return value (such as Attachments, As String). I found out that only the fields with a return value of Lookup value are causing the problem.

Has anyone encountered this yet?

Comment: I don't know what I did, but I can now save the Start a Task Process action. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using SharePoint designer 2013? This happened to me a while ago. After I closed it and opened it again and it would work (ensuring it reconnects to the site).

Comment: Really? Well, maybe it is also similar to my case. I remember that my SPD crashed and restarted itself... Very weird. I hope there's an official article explaining this!

Comment: @LesterNubla You seem surprised... if I had a dollar every time SharePoint Designer 2013 crashed on me, I'd be a millionaire :P

Comment: Hahaha!! @David, I don't really know the behavior of SharePoint because I am very new to this technology. I was administering IBM FileNet P8 last year. :)

Comment: So restarting is really a solution. :P I will make this as an accepted answer. Thanks!